# Running Java .jar and Windows .exe from bat file

Tags: c#, java, windows, batch-file, cmd

Situation is, i have 3 separate batch files in different locations running `start` commands
on .jar .exe and call command to open index.html through Firefox.

I want to create one global batch-file to run all of these one at a time.
***Extra*** *hint* would be to make a pause (several seconds) in between calling each one of those commands.

These are the commands i am executing in batch files:

```
echo majmun1
call C:\OKOLINA\additionConsoleApplication1.exe
echo majmun2
call C:\OKOLINA\addition1\jWebSocketSamples-2.0.jar
echo majmun3
call firefox.exe C:\OKOLINA\addition2\index.html
echo majmun4
exit
```

It only executes `call` the first one and stops.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `call` waits for the process to end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `start` istead:

```
echo majmun1
start C:\OKOLINA\additionConsoleApplication1.exe
echo majmun2
start C:\OKOLINA\addition1\jWebSocketSamples-2.0.jar
echo majmun3
start firefox.exe C:\OKOLINA\addition2\index.html
echo majmun4
exit
```

If you want to make a pause between `start`s, then you can use this little hack:

```
command 1
ping -w 1000 -n 5 127.0.0.1
command 2
```

It pings localhost 5 times (`-n 5`) and waits 1000ms (`-w 1000`) between each ping, effectively delaying execution of `command 2` for 5 seconds. (You can't use `pause` as it waits for a user to press Enter and there is no built-in delay command).

Comment: this was crucial for getting it to run from C#, I had a batch that just called java.exe, and it would always hang until my unit test finished, adding start to the front of the call fixed it, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `start` instead of `call` to launch your applications.

`call` calls one batch program from another (The filename parameter must have a `.bat` or `.cmd` extension).

On the other hand, `start` starts a separate command prompt window to run a specified program or command.